# How to create a sequence of strings between "start" and "end" strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sequence, ienumerable

Lets suppose I have the following strings:

```
string start = "ABC";
string end = "EEE";
```

I want to generate a collection of strings between those two, as if the characters were numbers, each one from A to Z. **They will always have three characters.** For example:

```
ABD
ABE
ABF
....// many strings, lets jump ahead
ABZ
ACA
....
AZZ
BAA
...
EEB
EEC
EED
```

I am trying to create a method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GenerateSequence(string start, string end)
{
    // while? for? do while?
    yield return ?;
}
```

But I really do not know where to begin. Am I reinventing the wheel? Is there a good algorithm to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Lets say I'm making a web crawler that will scrap a website with a "search box" that accepts those codes as input. In each search, I will get one result. I want all of the data (results) between the sequence.

Comment: Will both strings have the same length? What if one is `"A"` and the other is `"AAA"`? or `start: "B", end: "AA"` or `start: "AAA", end: "Z"`?

Comment: They will always be length == 3, let me update the question with that info.

Comment: @Dai since it's scraping someone key site the format should be fixed...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the link, I searched but did not find that. I believe this will solve my problem.

Comment: There are more https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+sequntial+string+increment ...